# ngxd doesn't invoke the output function inside the context

Tags: javascript, angular

I using [ngxd](https://github.com/IndigoSoft/ngxd#readme) to load component dynamic.

The docs says:

> inputs and outputs will binding automatically

But in my code I pass context to the component with `close` function. the `value` input it pass to component but when I emit `close` from the component, it won't trigger the `close` function inside the `fooContext`.

Why? how to fix that? it's should invoke `close` function and output on the console `in close`.

The code in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-simple-dynamic-yyc3ry?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts).

```
import {
  NgModule,
  Component,
  Input,
  Output,
  EventEmitter,
  Type,
  Directive
} from "@angular/core";
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { NgxdModule } from "@ngxd/core";

@Component({
  selector: "foo",
  template: `
    {{ value | json }}
    <button (click)="close.emit()">close</button>
  `
})
export class FooComponent {
  @Input() value;

  @Output() close = new EventEmitter();
}

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  template: `
    <ng-container *ngxComponentOutlet="cmp; context: fooContext">
    </ng-container>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  cmp = FooComponent;

  fooContext = {
    value: "val",
    close: () => {
      console.log("in close");
    }
  };
}

@NgModule({
  /**
   * Import NgxdModule
   */
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, NgxdModule],
  /**
   * Add components to declarations.
   */
  declarations: [AppComponent, FooComponent],
  /**
   * Add dynamics components to entryComponents.
   */
  entryComponents: [FooComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in this [thread](https://github.com/IndigoSoft/ngxd/issues/32).If you want to bind output then you have to create output in the component where you using ngxComponentOutlet. In your case it's AppComponent component.

If you want to listen click changes in AppComponent you can subscribe to the click event Emitter, something like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  template: `
    <ng-container *ngxComponentOutlet="cmp; context: fooContext">
    </ng-container>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  cmp = FooComponent;
  @Output() close = new EventEmitter();

  fooContext = {
    value: "val"
  };
   
  constructor() {
   this.close.subscribe(value => {
     console.log("inClose");
   });
  }

}
```

[Forked Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngxd-doesnt-invoke-the-output-function-inside-the-contex?file=src/app/app.module.ts)